# PyQt QPropertyAnimation not starting

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpropertyanimation

I have implemented a custom label that animates the font size. When defining the UI programatically, as in `AniLabelTest`, the animation works. However, when using the UI designed in QtCreator, the animation does not work. How could it be fixed?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSequentialAnimationGroup, QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel

from resources.utils import resource_path
from resources.widgets import AnimatedLabel


class AnimatedLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, increase, decrease, min_size, max_size, duration):
        super().__init__()
        self.labelFont = self.font()
        self.setText(text)
        self.ani_group = QSequentialAnimationGroup()

        if increase and decrease:
            duration = int(duration / 2)

        if increase:
            self.ani_increase = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'labelFontSize')
            self.ani_increase.setStartValue(min_size)
            self.ani_increase.setEndValue(max_size)
            self.ani_increase.setDuration(duration)
            self.ani_group.addAnimation(self.ani_increase)

        if decrease:
            self.ani_decrease = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'labelFontSize')
            self.ani_decrease.setStartValue(max_size)
            self.ani_decrease.setEndValue(min_size)
            self.ani_decrease.setDuration(duration)
            self.ani_group.addAnimation(self.ani_decrease)

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def labelFontSize(self):
        return self.labelFont.pointSize()

    @labelFontSize.setter
    def labelFontSize(self, size):
        self.labelFont.setPointSize(size)
        self.setFont(self.labelFont)

    def start(self):
        """
        Start animation
        """
        print("Animation started")
        self.setHidden(False)
        self.ani_group.start()


class AniLabelTest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AniLabelTest, self).__init__()
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        self.label = AnimatedLabel(f"test", True, True, 16, 60, 1000)

        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(self))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.label.start)


Ui_MainWindow, _ = uic.loadUiType(
    resource_path("resources/ui/mainwindow2.ui")
)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.hide()

        self.fdbckTargetLabel = AnimatedLabel(f"test", True, True, 16, 60, 1000)
        self.frame.layout().addWidget(self.fdbckTargetLabel, 0, 0)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.fdbckTargetLabel.start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = AniLabelTest()
    # test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The .ui file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>594</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget {
    font-size: 16pt
};


</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>START</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>ph</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>17</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuSettings">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Settings</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionChange_Settings"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuSettings"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionChange_Settings">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Change Settings</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I have tried implementing the start() in a separate thread using QRunnable and QThreadingPool but it does not work

Comment: Remove the style sheet of the central widget: the style sheets always take precedence over the palette and font (see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#font-prop)). If you want to set a default font for the whole application, use [`QApplication.setFont()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont), or set the font in the top level widget (you can do it in Designer too). Also, don't try to use threading for such things, since UI elements are **not** thread safe.

Comment: Also, be more careful when creating layouts: the parent argument of a QLayout constructor is the widget on which the layout will be installed to, and you cannot do `QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)` when `self` represents a QMainWindow, because QMainWindow has its own *private* layout which cannot be replaced. Either change that to `layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()` (without any argument) or `layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget())` (without calling `setLayout()` later).